# SQL Server execute too slow for multiple select

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
   CountryCode, CountryName, CountryEName, FirstShow, iseTicketFirstShow 
FROM 
   Tristar.dbo.COMCountry 
WHERE 
  ContinentName = 'Continent Name' AND iseTicket = 1 
  and CountryCode in 
    (select Distinct CountryCode 
     from eTicketSubAirport 
     where AirportCode in 
         (select DISTINCT eTDestinationAirport 
          from eTicketMain 
          where eTChecked=1 and eTDepartAirport='TPE')
    ) 
ORDER BY 
   iseTicketFirstShow DESC, FirstShow,CountryEName
```

The above code took 3 seconds....which is unaccepted. The 2 inner select execute very fast by themselves.

And if I took away one inner select, such as ....

```
SELECT 
   CountryCode, CountryName, CountryEName, FirstShow, iseTicketFirstShow 
FROM 
   Tristar.dbo.COMCountry 
WHERE 
   ContinentName = 'continent name' AND iseTicket = 1 
   and CountryCode in 
     (select Distinct CountryCode 
      from eTicketSubAirport) 
ORDER BY 
   iseTicketFirstShow DESC, FirstShow,CountryEName
```

This executes very fast too.

Hash Match too 79% of processing. [eTicketSubAirport]

I cannot take out any part of the select as they are all necessary....

Comment: what is your problem here.As you are saying in both the cases it runs fast then what you want to achieve?

Comment: An inner select in an inner select probably results in a horrible execution plan.  You might should try to convert those to joins.  (And/or make sure proper indexes are in place.)

Comment: Don't bother with `in (select Distinct ...` just use  `in (select ...`. Unlikely to affect the performance but just clutters the query up for no gain. Please post the actual execution plan XML.

Comment: first case runs very slow.
second case runs very fast. if I run each select separately, they are all very fast. with any of two selects, they are very fast too. But if there are 3 selects, then it took 3 seconds...

Comment: Try to convert the sub queries to joins instead, it seems like that shouldn't be too difficult. You could even save the CoutryCode list into a temporary table before the query, that would result in  much faster query too. But try the joins first.

Comment: Your subqueries might execute fast on their own, but given they are nested two levels deep, they will probably execute a very large number of times - at a glance once per country, possibly once per country to the power of the number of countries - assume 200 countries, that's 40000 times. This will add up. 40000 * 0.005 seconds (guess) is 4000 seconds, or 3 minutes 20 seconds. Indexes will also help.

Comment: I just tried taking away the distinct, it doesn't help.

Comment: set index for the fields ContinentName and Country Code. This is give you more fast result.

Comment: Maybe show us the schema and tell us what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: BTW to all people complaining about sub queries `IN` is a semi join already. Rewriting as a join using the `join` keyword may improve performance but if so it will be coincidental. Chances are if anything it will hurt performance as dupes then need to be removed with `DISTINCT` the OP needs to post the execution plan.

Comment: I change it to join and it works very well...Corbin is right inner select within another is horrible...Thank you guys

Comment: `and CountryCode in 
    (select Distinct CountryCode 
     from eTicketSubAirport 
     where AirportCode in 
         (select DISTINCT eTDestinationAirport 
          from eTicketMain 
          where eTChecked=1 and eTDepartAirport='TPE')
    )`. Is this necessary? I mean - are you trying to make sure that the countryCode value in COMCountry table is a valid one? If so, is there a need to do it?

Comment: @HamiltonWang - You might have lucked into getting a better plan on this occasion but there is no inherent reason why the rewrite should perform better. If you post both actual execution plans XML then I'll give you an explanation of why the rewrite helped in this case.

Comment: @HamiltonWang, while Martin is right that there is no guarantee that explicitly using a join would be faster than a subquery, but it does make it easier to read and understand the query in my opinion. I'm glad it helped you in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a join, it would looke like something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   Country.CountryCode, 
   Country.CountryName, 
   Country.CountryEName, 
   Country.FirstShow, 
   Country.iseTicketFirstShow 
FROM 
   Tristar.dbo.COMCountry AS Country
   INNER JOIN eTicketSubAirport ON Country.CountryCode = eTicketSubAirport.CountryCode
   INNER JOIN eTicketMain       ON eTicketSubAirport.AirportCode = eTicketMain.eTDestinationAirport
WHERE 
  Country.ContinentName = 'Continent Name' 
  AND Country.iseTicket = 1 
  AND eTicketMain.eTChecked = 1 
  AND eTicketMain.eTDepartAirport = 'TPE'
ORDER BY 
   Country.iseTicketFirstShow DESC, 
   Country.FirstShow,
   Country.CountryEName
```

Comment: You forgot the `DISTINCT` which would be required to remove any duplicates introduced by the join itself. And `CountryCode` in the select list needs to be disambiguated as it is present in two tables.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. @HamiltonWang could you post the execution plan as Martin suggests, i'd me interested too in learning more about reading them.

Comment: I tried it out, and it works well with **DISTINCT** added. Besides, I have to change all the table name such as **eTicketMain** to **eTicketMain m** and change **eTicketMain.eTDestinationAirport** to **m.eTDestinationAirport**, otherwise, error will occur.